# Installing ARM64 ubuntu vm on VmWare Fusion

Tags: vmware, iso, arm, vmware-fusion

Downloaded an Ubuntu 18.04 ARM iso image from 
 https://ubuntu.com/download/server/arm

In vmware fusion:

1. created a new virtual machine from iso image
2. Selected Linux->Ubuntu->64 bit
3. Install

It says `Operating System Not Found`

Tried this with Ubuntu 16 ARM image and ended up with the same error

If I install an x_86 image all works well.

What's missing in the ARM images?

Answer (score 1):

Your confusion is over what VMware can support.

VMware is not able to virtualize ARM infrastructure.  It can not run `arm64`, `armhf`, or `armel` images.  This is because VMware's "64 bit" is `x86_64`/`amd64` and NOT ARM.

ARM and traditional 32/64bit images are not the same, and therefore can't be interchanged in VMware.  VMware is only capable of running i386 and amd64 - the traditional x86 and x86_64 based - systems.

Comment: Okay got it. Is there any other way I can install an Ubuntu ARM image ?

Comment: Not without ARM hardware.  Raspberry Pis are not that pricey if you need a small ARM system.

Comment: @alokaggarwal VMware Fusion Public Tech Preview 21H1 supports ARM now

Answer (score 0):

[Qemu](https://www.qemu.org/) can emulate ARM architectures on a normal PC. See for example [Debian on ARM via QEMU](http://phwl.org/2021/qemu-armhf-debian/). However, it is more difficult to use than VMWare Fusion.